# Full page Javascript confetti not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a webpage with a full page confetti effect.
I have tried to make it full page but if I put text on the page the confetti effect will move to the bottom.
I have tried to change this in HTML/CSS but so far I couldn't get it fixed.
Would someone be able to help me with this?
Thanks in advance?

```js
var maxParticleCount = 70; //set max confetti count
    var particleSpeed = 1; //set the particle animation speed
    var startConfetti; //call to start confetti animation
    var stopConfetti; //call to stop adding confetti
    var toggleConfetti; //call to start or stop the confetti animation depending on whether it's already running
    var removeConfetti; //call to stop the confetti animation and remove all confetti immediately

    (function() {
     startConfetti = startConfettiInner;
     stopConfetti = stopConfettiInner;
     toggleConfetti = toggleConfettiInner;
     removeConfetti = removeConfettiInner;
     var colors = ["DodgerBlue", "OliveDrab", "Gold", "Pink", "SlateBlue", "LightBlue", "Violet", "PaleGreen", "SteelBlue", "SandyBrown", "Chocolate", "Crimson"]
     var streamingConfetti = false;
     var animationTimer = null;
     var particles = [];
     var waveAngle = 0;

     function resetParticle(particle, width, height) {
      particle.color = colors[(Math.random() * colors.length) | 0];
      particle.x = Math.random() * width;
      particle.y = Math.random() * height - height;
      particle.diameter = Math.random() * 10 + 5;
      particle.tilt = Math.random() * 10 - 10;
      particle.tiltAngleIncrement = Math.random() * 0.07 + 0.05;
      particle.tiltAngle = 0;
      return particle;
     }

     function startConfettiInner() {
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;
      window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
       return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function (callback) {
         return window.setTimeout(callback, 16.6666667);
        };
      })();
      var canvas = document.getElementById("confetti-canvas");
      if (canvas === null) {
       canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
       canvas.setAttribute("id", "confetti-canvas");
       canvas.setAttribute("style", "display:block;z-index:999999;pointer-events:none");
       document.body.appendChild(canvas);
       canvas.width = width;
       canvas.height = height;
       window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
       }, true);
      }
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      while (particles.length < maxParticleCount)
       particles.push(resetParticle({}, width, height));
      streamingConfetti = true;
      if (animationTimer === null) {
       (function runAnimation() {
        context.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        if (particles.length === 0)
         animationTimer = null;
        else {
         updateParticles();
         drawParticles(context);
         animationTimer = requestAnimFrame(runAnimation);
        }
       })();
      }
     }

     function stopConfettiInner() {
      streamingConfetti = false;
     }

     function removeConfettiInner() {
      stopConfetti();
      particles = [];
     }

     function toggleConfettiInner() {
      if (streamingConfetti)
       stopConfettiInner();
      else
       startConfettiInner();
     }

     function drawParticles(context) {
      var particle;
      var x;
      for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
       particle = particles[i];
       context.beginPath();
       context.lineWidth = particle.diameter;
       context.strokeStyle = particle.color;
       x = particle.x + particle.tilt;
       context.moveTo(x + particle.diameter / 2, particle.y);
       context.lineTo(x, particle.y + particle.tilt + particle.diameter / 2);
       context.stroke();
      }
     }

     function updateParticles() {
      var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;
      var particle;
      waveAngle += 0.01;
      for (var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++) {
       particle = particles[i];
       if (!streamingConfetti && particle.y < -15)
        particle.y = height + 100;
       else {
        particle.tiltAngle += particle.tiltAngleIncrement;
        particle.x += Math.sin(waveAngle);
        particle.y += (Math.cos(waveAngle) + particle.diameter + particleSpeed) * 0.5;
        particle.tilt = Math.sin(particle.tiltAngle) * 15;
       }
       if (particle.x > width + 20 || particle.x < -20 || particle.y > height) {
        if (streamingConfetti && particles.length <= maxParticleCount)
         resetParticle(particle, width, height);
        else {
         particles.splice(i, 1);
         i--;
        }
       }
      }
     }
    })();
```

```css
 body, html {
     height: 100%;
    }
    body {
     height: 100%;
     background-color:#ff5abd;
     background-image: url("../img/bg.png");
     background-position: center;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: cover;
     position: absolute;
     font-family: Roboto;
     overflow: hidden;

    }
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
          <meta name="description" content="">
          <meta name="author" content="">

          <title></title>


          <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-1.css" />

        </head>


        <body onload="startConfetti()">
          <div class="text">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborump>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborump>

          </div>

          <script src="js/confetti.js"></script>

        </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Stef and welcome to the site. The JS script you provided will always "append" (read "add") the area where the confetti drops as the last part of your page. This area has an id of "confetti-canvas" which you can give styling to be adding a rule to the style section of your page:

```
#confetti-canvas {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
}
```

This will move the canvas to the top of your page, and it will ignore the regular page flow so it lies on top of your text.